# Return existing csv file in django as download

Tags: django, angular, csv, django-rest-framework

I have a csv file in an assets folder with a few entries in my django project, and I want my angular frontend to be able to download this csv file. The existing examples show how to create a new csv file and send that, but I don't need to create a new csv file, I already have one, so how does the view/controller have to look? How can I return a csv file in django and make it able to be downloaded by my frontend?

Please don't mention this reference, as it is not my intention to create a new csv file:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/outputting-csv/

Comment: Is your assets folder where your static files or media files are served from? Is the csv file referenced by a FileField in a model?

Comment: No, there is just a simple csv file, no other files. At this point, models are not even important, so no its not referenced. It just needs to be downloaded

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) object to return a file from a view, pass `as_attachment=True` to offer the file to the user as a download

```
def my_view(request):
    return FileResponse(open('path/to/filename.csv', 'rb'), as_attachment=True)
```